# Cannot change background color in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-background

I cannot change my background to the color blue and when I try to my desktop background goes black. I tried to do `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true` but it still does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a confirmed bug. See [the bugreport in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1173818): Unable to set solid colors and gradients as desktop background in gnome-control-center

Answer (score 5):

Initially you should be able to pick & use either the default solid blue, (#023c88) or that blue with a vertical or horizontal gradient (defaults to secondary of #5789ca

However once you open the custom color selector & choose anything then entries are made in rgb(X,XX,XXX) which produces black & you can't change that from Appearances > Background

I'd suggest opening dconf-editor > org.gnome.desktop.background & either reset color-shading type, primary color & secondary color back to defaults or enter the color(s) you wish directly using #XXXXXX

Comment: I would comment on post @doug but I have no enough reputation.
I would like to confirm that solution works just now. Be sure to click on the entry for primary-color and change from rgb to 6 digit hex form
example: rgb(250,235,215) -> #FAEBD7 Hope people find this while this bug lasts. Desktop background can improve your productivity if it does not hurt your eyes (no kidding!).